Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-dynamic-link-domain)
I seem to be stuck in a loop of not being able to figure this out. I want to allow my users to have a passwordless signup and only use their email in my web app.
According the the firebase docs, first I need to allow that option on the console. I did that.
Then I need to construct the ActionCodeSettings.
const actionCodeSettings = {
  url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.example.android',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12'
  },
  dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
};

I went into my settings on the firebase app and made appName-59ce1.firebaseapp.com. I used that exactly.
I also tried this with localhost because thats where I am testing it but still the same error.
The docs then tell me to configure a dynamic link. So I follow the link to the firebase console and am presented with:

Dynamic Links is no longer supported, and will stop working on August 25, 2025.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious here? or have they just made it impossible to use this now?
